# как закруглить углы progress bar c# и сделать его еще меньше по высоте?

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно закруглить углы у прогресс бара... Как на скрине и сделать таким же по высоте, стандартных параметров не нашел в этом плане, может кастомные какие-нибудь юзать?
Вот такой нужно сделать: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот какой у меня 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как еще цвет изменить у него? Что бы тоже белым был.

Comment: нужно создать свой собственный контрол. Но вообще в таких вопросах принято указывать к чему относится вопрос - к винформс или впф.

Comment: @Andrew, winforms

Comment: В WPF такое делается очень легко, а вот в Winforms наверное вам придется наследоваться от прогресс-бара и переопределять ему `OnPaint`, то есть написать свой собственный рендер прогресс-бара, [как-то так](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1517179/12888024).

Comment: просмотри здесь реализацию прогрессбара. https://github.com/ukushu/TextProgressBar Она кривая и здесь много лишнего относительно того что тебе нужно. Но принцип того что нужно сделать ты можешь подцепить именно отсюда